# How to indent code in pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Here is a python code sample.

```
r = request.get(...)
....
....
....
print r.text
```

Now I want to write an function.

```
def get_response(url):
r = request.get(...)
....
....
....
print r.text
```

My target is :

```
def get_response(url):
    r = request.get(...)
    ....
    ....
    ....
    print r.text
```

Adding tab in each line is very inconvenient. Is there any short cut for this situation? My ide is `PyCharm`.

Comment: are you trying to reformat the code?

Comment: press  `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L`  to format the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the lines you want to indent and hit tab. it'll move them all across.

Comment: do you mean remove the tab from the text? highlighting and shift + tab will reverse it